# org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener occasionally not found when starting Tomcat in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, struts2, tiles

I'm using Tomcat inside Eclipse. This problem happens to me whenever I open Eclipse for the first time every day (or close it and re-open it anytime). I have to clean it or re-add the server to make the Tomcat server working.

I'm wondering if anyone was having the same problem. Any help would be appreciated.

The following is the exception, but the `StrutsTilesListener` class is out there and I'm pretty sure about it:

```
Feb 9, 2012 3:51:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1688)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1533)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:507)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:124)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5260)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: same scenario, same problem...

Answer (score 0):

```
**<listener>
<listener-class>org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener</listener-class>
</listener>**
```

Use the above Listener in our web.xml file

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that eclipse tomcat plugin puts some configuration (for Eclipse WTP) including classpath definitions into tomcat for my webapp context, in conf/Catalina/localhost. 
This is automatic.
The classpaths include most of the jars but not all of them.
So you better keep the server and ide separate.
http://struts.1045723.n5.nabble.com/ClassNotFoundException-StrutsTilesListener-td3553672.html

Answer (score 0):

I was using eclipse Luna for Java Developers (64bits) and I installed Web Tools Platform (WTP) over this version for work with Tomcat 6.0.39 inside eclipse. Also got this same weird behavior. 
After install & use a clean eclipse Luna EE edition, no more `ClassNotFoundException` with Struts2 Tiles jar.

Don't know why that it happened and don't know why isn't happening now, but I'm using eclipse EE for 4 hours and it's ok since then.

Which version of eclipse are you using?