# ConfigureListener java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat7, netbeans-7

**I want to Deploy a java webarchive Porject with NetBeans. I get an error "ClassNotFoundException" from Tomcat-Server.**

**How can I find out which Java class is missing?**

**the error from NetBeans (version 7.2)**

```
    Undeploying ...
    undeploy?path=/Project
    OK - Undeployed application at context path /Project
    In-place deployment at C:\JEE6\NetBeans-Projekt-von-WorkflowAgent\Project_EE\build\web
    deploy?config=file%3A%2FC%3A%2FUsers%2FNoob%2FAppData%2FLocal%2FTemp%2Fcontext5399671692696655653.xml&path=/BARCODEserver
    FAIL - Deployed application at context path /BARCODEserver but context failed to start
    C:\JEE6\NetBeans-Projekt-von-WorkflowAgent\WORKFLOWagent_EE\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1063: The module has not been deployed.
    See the server log for details.
```

**Tomcat log throw the following error message:**

```
Okt 15, 2012 8:03:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
Schwerwiegend: Error configuring application listener of class com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:532)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:514)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:536)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1453)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1445)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:860)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:357)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1813)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Okt 15, 2012 8:03:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
Schwerwiegend: Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219663/showing-error-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-struts2-tiles-struts/12845690#12845690

Comment: As the stacktrace plainly tells you which class is missing, I suspect you may be asking about determining which jar contains the missing class?  Can you clarify/correct your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It tells you: `com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener`

See: [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException : com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848341/classnotfoundexception-com-sun-faces-config-configurelistener-for-jsf-project-u)

Comment: Thanks, I've downloaded JSF.jar in / WEB-INF/lib and the porblem was solved